# Existence and Uniqueness of 2D SDE: $dx=v\,dt+dB\\dv = -κx\,dt-\alpha\,v\,dt+h\,dB$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $B(t)$ be a 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Consider the Ito integral form
$$dx=v\,dt+dB\\dv = -κx\,dt-\alpha\,v\,dt+h\,dB$$
where $\kappa$, $\alpha$ and $h$ are positive constants. I would like to prove the existence and uniqueness of this 2D SDE. I think that the reference could be the following theorem.

> **Theorem.**
> For the SDE
> $$
> \mathrm{d} X=G(t, X(t)) \mathrm{d} t+H(t, X(t)) \mathrm{d} W(t), \quad X\left(t_{0}\right)=X_{0},
> $$
> assume the following hold.
> (1) Both $G(t, x)$ and $H(t, x)$ are continuous on $(t, x) \in\left[t_{0}, T\right] \times \mathbb{R}$.
> (2) The coefficient functions $G$ and $H$ satisfy the Lipschitz condition
> $$
> |G(t, x)-G(t, y)|+|H(t, x)-H(t, y)| \leq K|x-y| .
> $$
> (3) The coefficient functions $G$ and H satisfy a growth condition in the second variable,
> $$
> |G(t, x)|^{2}+|H(t, x)|^{2} \leq K\left(1+|x|^{2}\right),
> $$
> for all $t \in\left[t_{0}, T\right]$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
> Then the SDE has a strong solution on $\left[t_{0}, T\right]$ that is continuous with probability 1 and
> $$
> \sup _{t \in\left[t_{0}, T\right]} \mathbb{E}\left[X^{2}(t)\right]<\infty,
> $$
> and for each given Wiener process $W(t)$, the corresponding strong solutions are pathwise unique, which means that if $X$ and $Y$ are two strong solutions, then
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left[\sup _{t \in\left[t_{0}, T\right]}|X(t)-Y(t)|=0\right]=1 .
> $$

(I took it from *Dunbar, S.R. Mathematical Modeling in Economics and Finance: Probability, Stochastic Processes, and Differential Equations; Vol. 49, American Mathematical Soc., 2019.*)

In my case I have that $X=(x,v)$ and $G$, for example, is the matrix:
$$G(t,X) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\-\kappa & -\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$
But how can I prove the conditions (1)-(3) of the theorem above?

Comment: $G(t,X)$ is not only the system matrix, but the linear function, $G(t,X)=G·X$. As linear function it is Lipschitz and sub-linear in any sense.

Comment: @LutzLehmann do you mean that the existence of strong solution is gained by linearity?

Comment: Yes, one could summarize the conditions in that the coefficient functions behave locally (continuity) and globally (growth) not worse than linear functions.

Comment: Ok thank you! It's clear.